# Jquery toggle class on select when selecting the placeholder option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am very new on JQuery, and despite my research and workarounds, i don't find out the right way to code what I want to achieve here.

So, here's the situation. I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<select name="your-country" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="">Your Country*</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

I want my dropdown list to be grey whenever the first placeholder "Your Country*" option is selected, and black when another option is selected.

```
select{
    color: #000;
}
select.my-placeholder{
    color: #666 !important;
}
```

I want to create a simple jquery block of code that adds the class `.my-placeholder` whenever the first option (with no value) is selected, and discard it whenever another option is selected. (I want **no change** in the HTML code)

How can I achieve that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will respond to `change` event and selection check the value and add corresponding class

```js
function updateColor() {
  let getSelectedValue = $('select[name="your-country"]').val();
  if (getSelectedValue === "") {

    $('select[name="your-country"]').find('option').addClass('my-placeholder');
  } else {

    $('select[name="your-country"]').find('option').removeClass('my-placeholder').addClass('select');

  }
}
```

```css
.select {
  color: red;
}

.my-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="your-country" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" onchange="updateColor()">
    <option value="">Your Country*</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```